# Method with a bool return

Tags: c#, if-statement, return

I was making a method with a `bool` return value and I had a problem:

This works

```
private bool CheckAll()
{
  //Do stuff
  return true;
}
```

But this dosn't, the method can't detect a return value if it's in a IF-statement.

```
private bool CheckAll()
{
  if (...)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: All your code branches should return some value, like for instance if the condition inside if is false, compiler has no idea what to return in that case. You should explicitly specify return (default) value outside if block.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
private bool CheckAll()
{
    if ( ....)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

When the if-condition is false the method doesn't know what value should be returned (you probably get an error like "not all paths return a value").

As [CQQL pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12624764/1376657) if you mean to return true when your if-condition is true you could have simply written:

```
private bool CheckAll()
{
    return (your_condition);
}
```

If you have side effects, and you want to handle them before you return, the first (long) version would be required.

Answer (score 5):

Long version:

```
private bool booleanMethod () {
    if (your_condition) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But since you are using the outcome of your condition as the result of the method you can shorten it to

```
private bool booleanMethod () {
    return your_condition;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
     public bool roomSelected()
    {
        int a = 0;
        foreach (RadioButton rb in GroupBox1.Controls)
        {
            if (rb.Checked == true)
            {
                a = 1;
            }
        }
        if (a == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

this how I solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to explain this,

```
public bool CheckInputs(int a, int b){
public bool condition = true;

if (a > b || a == b)
{
   condition = false;
}
else
{
   condition = true;
}

return condition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the else portion. If all the conditions are false then else will work where you haven't declared and returned anything from else branch.

```
private bool CheckALl()
{
  if(condition)
  {
    return true
  }
  else
  {
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
public bool roomSelected()
{
    foreach (RadioButton rb in GroupBox1.Controls)
    {
        if (rb.Checked == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure neither of these options were available in C# when you asked the question but nowadays you can do it like the following:

```
// Return with ternary conditional operator.
private bool CheckAll()
{
    return (your_condition) ? true : false;
}

// Alternatively as an expression bodied method.
private bool CheckAll() => (your_condition) ? true : false;
```

Comment: This does not compile. Please do not provide invalid C# code.